# How to write this query in Doctrine2 ? (subquery + JOINs)

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

This is the query I want to implement using Doctrine2 :

```
SELECT  d1_.codeLieu AS codeLieu1, d1_.nomLieu AS nomLieu2, d1_.lngLieu AS lngLieu3, d1_.latLieu AS latLieu4, m2_.libelleMention AS libelleMention5, t3_.libelleType AS libelleType6, COUNT( b0_.id ) AS sclr0
 FROM   Delegation       d1_  
  INNER JOIN   EtablissementBac e5_   ON e5_.delegation_id = d1_.codeLieu 
  INNER JOIN TypeBac          t3_
  INNER JOIN   MentionBac       m2_ 
  LEFT JOIN    Bac              b0_   
                          ON b0_.etabBac_id = e5_.codeLieu   -- 1st clause
                          AND b0_.typeBac_id = t3_.codeType   -- 2nd clause
                          AND b0_.mentionBac_id = m2_.codeMention    -- 3rd clause
WHERE m2_.codeMention IN ('TB',  'B')
AND t3_.codeType IN ('114',  '129')
AND d1_.codeLieu IN('01','02','03','38','49','58')
GROUP BY d1_.codeLieu, m2_.codeMention, m2_.libelleMention, t3_.codeType, t3_.libelleType, t3_.abbrType
ORDER BY d1_.codeLieu ASC , b0_.mentionBac_id ASC , b0_.typeBac_id ASC
```

I'm having some trouble with the 2nd and 3rd clauses of the `Bac` table. Any thoughts of how can I implent it using Doctrine2 ? Since the request is built dynamically, I cannot use native SQL, that's why I need to build it using DQL.

Comment: Anyone could help me please ?

Comment: What do you want as output ? an object ? an array of scalar result ? This is not a hard query.

Comment: an array of arrays (as in the select part)

Answer (score 0):

Using the "Arbitrary JOIN Syntax".

```
$qb
    ->select(array('d.codeLieu', 'd.nomLieu', 'd.lngLieu', 'd.latLieu', 'm.libelleMention', 't.libelleType', 'COUNT(b.id) AS sclr'))
    ->from('PFA\SIGBundle\Entity\Delegation', 'd')
    ->innerJoin('PFA\SIGBundle\Entity\EtablissementBac', 'e', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('IDENTITY(e.delegation)', 'd.codeLieu'))
    ->innerJoin('PFA\SIGBundle\Entity\TypeBac', 't')
    ->innerJoin('PFA\SIGBundle\Entity\MentionBac', 'm')
    ->leftJoin('PFA\SIGBundle\Entity\Bac', 'b', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->andX(
        $qb->expr()->eq('IDENTITY(b.etabBac)', 'e.codeLieu'),
        $qb->expr()->eq('IDENTITY(b.typeBac)', 't.codeType'),
        $qb->expr()->eq('IDENTITY(b.mentionBac)', 'm.codeMention')
    ))
    ->where( $qb->expr()->andX(
        $qb->expr()->in('m.codeMention', ':codeMention'),
        $qb->expr()->in('t.codeType', ':codeType'),
        $qb->expr()->in('d.codeLieu', ':codeLieu')
    ))
    ->groupBy('d.codeLieu')
    ->addGroupBy('m.codeMention')
    ->addGroupBy('m.libelleMention')
    ->addGroupBy('t.codeType')
    ->addGroupBy('t.libelleType')
    ->addGroupBy('t.abbrType')
    ->orderBy('d.codeLieu', 'ASC')
    ->addOrderBy('m.codeMention', 'ASC')
    ->addOrderBy('t.codeType', 'ASC')
    ->setParameters(array(
        'codeMention' => array('TB', 'B'),
        'codeType' => array('114', '129'),
        'codeLieu' => array('01', '02', '03', '38', '49', '58')
    ));
```

Do a `$qb->getQuery()->getSql()` to see if this matches you original query.